# Checking what I have imported in the REPL?

Tags: scala

In my Scala REPL, is there any command I can use to:

- Check what I have imported?
- Check if a specific class / object is imported?

Thanks

Comment: the easiest way is to check when you call object/class whether it emit no-class exception. But likely this is not the answer you are waiting for - maybe you can add what you would like to achieve in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding 1): Yes, you can

```
scala> :imports
 1) import java.lang._             (145 types, 150 terms)
 2) import scala._                 (798 types, 806 terms)
 3) import scala.Predef._          (16 types, 167 terms, 96 are implicit)
```

Regarding 2): There are several ways, but why don't you just try to use the class in question? Besides that, you can also do

```
scala> :type Foo
<console>:8: error: not found: value Foo
       Foo
       ^

scala> :type List
scala.collection.immutable.List.type
```